# Build error in JSONCPP (Visual Studio2010)

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I downloaded `JSONCPP` from GitHub. I included header file `Json.h` and wrote simple code as shown in picture. But i am getting link errors. Can you please help in using `JSONCPP`.

> lINK ERROR: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   Json::Reader::Reader(void)" (??0Reader@Json@@QAE@XZ) referenced in
>   function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'read''(void)"
>   (??__Eread@@YAXXZ)[![MY code][1]][1]

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <json.h>

Json::Reader read;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is better to post code here, not images of code. This helps us help you quicker.

Comment: That is the small piece of code I have written

Comment: Can you remove the image and paste your code instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting linker errors because `json.h` file contains only class and method definitions and no actual implementation. To resolve this problem you have to generate *amalgamated* source from the `JsonCpp` and include its files into your project. See `Readme.md` file in the project root for the additional info.

> sonCpp is provided with a script to generate a single header and a
>   single source file to ease inclusion into an existing project. The
>   amalgamated source can be generated at any time by running the
>   following command from the top-directory (this requires Python 2.6):
>
> python amalgamate.py

Another option would be compiling `JSONCPP` source to the `.lib` file and use its with your project.

Comment: I did not find JSON.cpp file in entire directory :(

Comment: It will be created when you run `amalgamate.py` script.

Comment: I built lib_json.lib by using VS solution ( provided with JSONCPP) which is in msvc2010 folder. Can we use this lib ?

Comment: @user2329702 Sure. Simply add reference to in in you project options.

Comment: Check that runtime settings for your project and `JSONCpp` library are the same. See project Options->c/c++->Code Generation->Runtime